# Failed to update marvel license

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-marvel

I have an elasticsearch cluster in our close environment (no internet connection). 
Few days ago, marvel's license in my elasticsearch cluster has expired, so I downloaded the free basic license which elastic provides in their site.

I tried to update the license with the following command :

curl -XPUT -u admin 'http://host:port/_license' -d @/path/to/bla.json

and the output I received was :

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}

Can you help me update my license ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you incorporated <host> and <port> in your `http://` request URL  ?

Comment: This might be happening because the license you are trying to install doesn't support the features as supported by older version. hence you can try this

Comment: can you try `--data-binary` instead of `-d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was actually the json itself. 
Thanks anyway for your help guys :)

Comment: But what was the solution?  5 months later, and I'm having the same headache.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the license you are trying to install doesn't support the features as supported by older version. hence you can try this

```
 curl -XPUT -u admin 'http://<host>:<port>/_license?acknowledge=true' -d @license.json
```

This sets `acknowledge` parameter to be `true` so that you are aware of changes.

Not tried though ! Hope this helps...

**EDIT**

You can try to install the updated version as follows:

1) Download the licence '.zip' file

```
 wget https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/license/2.2.0/license-2.2.0.zip
```

2) Install the plugins using the zip files

```
 bin/plugin install file:///path-of-zip-file
```

Comment: I'm receiving the same error message with the suggested command.

Comment: you cab try installing the new version, not sure though if it will solve the problem. Still you can give it a try, I am editing in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the content of license.json manually to the place where  "@license.json" lies in.Like this:

curl -XPUT -u admin 'http://:/_license?acknowledge=true' -d '{"license":.......}'